# url change without hash

Tags: javascript, html, url, history

I want to change url when i open big image in pop up window on a current page with preview images. I don't want use window.location.hash feature because i want to manipulate with new url through PHP next and i found this complex to made it with hash. So, I found that I can use HTML5 feature to make this.

```
window.history.pushState(“object or string”, “Title”, “/new-url”);
```

My problem is: I want to remove this new-url from page when i close big image. How can i make this, without using

```
window.history.back();
```

?

Thanks.

Comment: I vaguely recall that it's called `pop state`. Try googling on that phrase.

Answer (score 1):

Closing the image is **not** analogous to pressing the back button in the browser. It is analogous to following another link back to the original page. So there's no need to go back. Just `pushState` again, back to the original URL.

On the other hand, if the person *does* click the back button in their browser, you want that to bring them back to the original page too. So you need to listen for the `popstate` event, and, when it's fired, run a function which will remove the popup image:

```
window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) {
    hideimage();
}
```

Read [more about the HTML5 history API](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html).

Comment: I'm looking for window.history.pushState(“object or string”, “Title”, “original url”); But I can't figure out how to make this? This doesn't work window.history.pushState(“object or string”, “Title”, “original "");

Comment: Yeah, this should do it.